# Customising error bars in Mathematica 12

Tags: plotting

In Mathematica 12, `ErrorListPlot` have now been integrated into `ListPlot` with the use of `Around[]`.

I can't find any documentation on how to edit the appearance of the error bars which are now generated by `ListPlot`. Any mention on official Wolfram pages still directs to the `ErrorListPlot` page.

The default styling of the error bars is simply a straight line from the centre of the point.

Does anyone know how to adjust the styling of the error bars in the `ListPlot` environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the **IntervalMarker** and **IntervalMarkersStyle** options. They allow you to customize the appearance of the markers.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll take a look!

Comment: Was absolutely what I was looking for. Well done for finding that it isn't highlighted very well anywhere!